# Error in dotnet restore in executing a docker build in project .net 6 use layers

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I'm trying executing a "**docker build**" in my application **.Net 6.0**, but I receive an **error in Dotnet restore in Dockerfile**.
The application executing normally local, not any error.

**Docker command:**

```
docker build -t aspnetcore-docker-image .
```

**Error in terminal:**

```
=> ERROR [build 7/9] RUN dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj                                              0.2s
------
 > [build 7/9] RUN dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj:
#11 0.185 Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
#11 0.185 Possible reasons for this include:
#11 0.185   * You intended to execute a .NET program:
#11 0.185       The application 'restore' does not exist.
#11 0.185   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
#11 0.185       It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
#11 0.185       Install a .NET SDK from:
#11 0.185         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj]: exit code: 145
```

**My Dockerfile**

```
# .NET Core SDK
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS build

# Sets the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy Projects
#COPY *.sln .
COPY Src/DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj ./DevFreela.API/
COPY Src/DevFreela.Application/DevFreela.Application.csproj ./DevFreela.Application/
COPY Src/DevFreela.Core/DevFreela.Core.csproj ./DevFreela.Core/
COPY Src/DevFreela.Infrastructure/DevFreela.Infrastructure.csproj ./DevFreela.Infrastructure/

# .NET Core Restore
RUN dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj

# Copy All Files
COPY Src ./

# .NET Core Build and Publish
RUN dotnet publish ./DevFreela.Api/DevFreela.Api.csproj -c Release -o /publish

# ASP.NET Core Runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /publish ./

EXPOSE 80 5195 7066
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5195;https://+:7066

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DevFreela.API.dll"]
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

**Complete terminal log:**

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 938B                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                       0.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 13.14kB                                                                                       0.0s
 => [runtime 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0@sha256:26ef9dc4aa354cc4aa4ae533c97f92d0d72c5e848f6968660be51d9  0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/9] COPY Src/DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj ./DevFreela.API/                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [build 4/9] COPY Src/DevFreela.Application/DevFreela.Application.csproj ./DevFreela.Application/                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 5/9] COPY Src/DevFreela.Core/DevFreela.Core.csproj ./DevFreela.Core/                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [build 6/9] COPY Src/DevFreela.Infrastructure/DevFreela.Infrastructure.csproj ./DevFreela.Infrastructure/       0.0s
 => ERROR [build 7/9] RUN dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj                                              0.2s
------
 > [build 7/9] RUN dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj:
#11 0.185 Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
#11 0.185 Possible reasons for this include:
#11 0.185   * You intended to execute a .NET program:
#11 0.185       The application 'restore' does not exist.
#11 0.185   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
#11 0.185       It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
#11 0.185       Install a .NET SDK from:
#11 0.185         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj]: exit code: 145
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the `aspnet` image which doesn't contain the SDK, so you can't build using that. You need the `sdk` image for the first part of your Dockerfile like this

```
# .NET Core SDK
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

# Sets the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy Projects
#COPY *.sln .
COPY Src/DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj ./DevFreela.API/
COPY Src/DevFreela.Application/DevFreela.Application.csproj ./DevFreela.Application/
COPY Src/DevFreela.Core/DevFreela.Core.csproj ./DevFreela.Core/
COPY Src/DevFreela.Infrastructure/DevFreela.Infrastructure.csproj ./DevFreela.Infrastructure/

# .NET Core Restore
RUN dotnet restore ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj

# Copy All Files
COPY Src ./

# .NET Core Build and Publish
RUN dotnet publish ./DevFreela.Api/DevFreela.Api.csproj -c Release -o /publish

# ASP.NET Core Runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /publish ./

EXPOSE 80 5195 7066
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5195;https://+:7066

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DevFreela.API.dll"]
```